# Is there stomp over websocket in PHP?

Tags: php, http, stomp

I  use Node.js to run STOMP over WebSocket because it supports custom headers. When HTTP handshake, the server needs a cookie to check auth, not the token in the address.

As PHPer, I want to use this in PHP, but search google for a long time and found no way. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

STOMP is not limited to Node.js, or Java, etc.  There are

- a [STOMP PECL extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stomp.php) for PHP,
- PHP STOMP libraries, e.g [Stomp-PHP](https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php),
- and general messaging libraries that support STOMP,
  e.g. [Enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-bundle)'s [STOMP transport](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/transport/stomp.md) layer, or [Laravel-Queue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/laravel-queue)

Regarding your specific scenario, it's hard to come up with a straight-up answer without knowing more details but here is an [example](https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php-examples/blob/4c6974511b5758b8d93fe8eca91e30bebdb85f95/src/transformation.php) from the stomp-php library samples hat sets a custom header:

> ```
> use Stomp\Client;
> use Stomp\SimpleStomp;
> use Stomp\Transport\Map;
>
>
> // make a connection
> $client = new Client('tcp://localhost:61613');
> $stomp = new SimpleStomp($client);
>
>
> // send a message to the queue
> $body = array('city' => 'Belgrade', 'name' => 'Dejan');
> $header = array();
> $header['transformation'] = 'jms-map-json';
> $mapMessage = new Map($body, $header);
> $client->send('/queue/test', $mapMessage);
> echo 'Sending array: ';
> print_r($body);
>
> $stomp->subscribe('/queue/test', 'transform-test', 'client', null, ['transformation' => 'jms-map-json']);
> /** @var Map $msg */
> $msg = $stomp->read();
>
> // extract
> if ($msg != null) {
>     echo 'Received array: ';
>     print_r($msg->map);
>     // mark the message as received in the queue
>     $stomp->ack($msg);
> } else {
>     echo "Failed to receive a message\n";
> }
> ```

Comment: thank you very much .I try this lib(stomp) before ,however the client can't custome header,I give it up. sorry for my poor English.

Comment: any of the libraries you mention do stomp over websocket.  you need to use something like : https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php/  to make it work

Answer (score 0):

you need a websocket stream wrapper if you want to connect using a protocol

Answer (score 0):

You can use php-stomp-frame

https://github.com/jeeinn/php-stomp-frame

composer require jeeinn/php-stomp-frame

```
public function getStompMessage(): array
{
    $stompFrame = new Frame();
    $connectFrame = $stompFrame->setLogin($this->ss['login'], $this->ss['password'])
        ->setHeartBeat(0, 10000)->getConnect();
    $subscribeFrame = $stompFrame->getSubscribe($this->ss['queue']);
    $client = new Client($this->ss['host']);
    $client->text($connectFrame);
    $client->text($subscribeFrame);
    $response = [];
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 3) {
        sleep(5);
        try {
            $message = $client->receive();
            if (empty($message) || in_array($message, self::BYTE)) {
                $i++;
                continue;
            }
            $parsed = $stompFrame->parser($message);
            if ($parsed['command'] == $this::STOMP_COMMAND_ERROR) {
                $this->logger($this::INFO, 'STOMP return with ERROR command:', $parsed['body']);
                $client->close();
                break;
            }
            if (($parsed['command'] == $this::STOMP_COMMAND_MESSAGE) || ($parsed['body'])) {
                    return json_decode($parsed['body'], true);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger($this::ERROR, 'STOMP error', (array)$e->getMessage());
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $response;
}
```